# The other side's version of one tailed Chebyshev's inequality?

Tags: probability

[A one-tailed version of Chebyshev's inequality](http://www.se16.info/hgb/cheb.htm) is that for t>0
$$P[X-E(X) \geq t] \leq \frac{1}{1 + t^2/Var(X)}$$
i.e. $$P[X-E(X)\geq t] \leq \frac{Var(X)}{Var(X) + t^2}$$

I heard someone claimed that the inequality is also true for the other side
$$P[X-E(X)\leq t] \leq \frac{Var(X)}{Var(X) + t^2}$$

I briefly looked through [the proof of the one-tailed version of Chebyshev's inequality](http://www.se16.info/hgb/cheb.htm#OTProof), and it doesn't seem to work for the other side's version. So I was wondering if the other side isn't true?

Has the other side version been studied before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other side cannot be true in general, as then we would have for $X \in L^2(P)$
\begin{align*}
  1 &\le P(X - E(X)\le t) + P(X - E(X)\ge t)\\
    &\le \frac{2V(X)}{V(X) + t^2}\\
    &\to 0, \quad t \to \infty
\end{align*}
which is absurd.

But of course for $t < 0$ we will have (applying the first version to $-X$)
\begin{align*}
 P(X - E(X) \le t) &= P\bigl(-X - E(-X) \ge -t\bigr)\\
    &\le \frac{V(-X)}{V(-X) + (-t)^2}\\
    &= \frac{V(X)}{V(X) + t^2}
\end{align*}